# Nest.js + Mikro-ORM: Collection of entity not initialized when using createQueryBuilder and leftJoin

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm using Nest.js, and considering migrating from TypeORM to Mikro-ORM. I'm using the [`nestjs-mikro-orm`](https://github.com/dario1985/nestjs-mikro-orm) module. But I'm stuck on something that seems very simple...

I've 3 entities, `AuthorEntity`, `BookEntity` and `BookMetadata`. From my `Author` module, I try to left join the `Book` and `BookMetadata` tables with the `createQueryBuilder` method. But when running my query, I'm getting an error where `Collection<BookEntity> of entity AuthorEntity[3390] not initialized`. However columns from the `Author` table are well retrieved.

My 3 entities:

```js
@Entity()
@Unique({ properties: ['key'] })
export class AuthorEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property({ length: 255 })
  key!: string;

  @OneToMany('BookEntity', 'author', { orphanRemoval: true })
  books? = new Collection<BookEntity>(this);
}

@Entity()
export class BookEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => AuthorEntity)
  author!: AuthorEntity;

  @OneToMany('BookMetadataEntity', 'book', { orphanRemoval: true })
  bookMetadata? = new Collection<BookMetadataEntity>(this);
}

@Entity()
@Unique({ properties: ['book', 'localeKey'] })
export class BookMetadataEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property({ length: 5 })
  localeKey!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => BookEntity)
  book!: BookEntity;
}
```

And the service file where I run my query:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthorService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(AuthorEntity)
    private readonly authorRepository: EntityRepository<AuthorEntity>,
  ) {}

  async findOneByKey(props: { key: string; localeKey: string; }): Promise<AuthorEntity> {
    const { key, localeKey } = props;

    return this.authorRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('a')
      .select(['a.*', 'b.*', 'c.*'])
      .leftJoin('a.books', 'b')
      .leftJoin('b.bookMetadata', 'c')
      .where('a.key = ?', [key])
      .andWhere('c.localeKey = ?', [localeKey])
      .getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Might be not related, but I also noticed that there is [a special `autoLoadEntities: true`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities) for TypeORM users  using Nest.js. Is there something similar for Mikro-ORM? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mapping of multiple entities from single query is not yet supported, it is planned for v4. You can subscribe here: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/440

In v3 you need to use 2 queries to load 2 entities, which for your use case is much easier without the QB involved.

```js
return this.authorRepository.findOne({ key }, ['books']);
```

Or you could use `qb.execute()` to get the raw results and map them yourself, but you would also have to manually alias all the fields to get around duplicities (`Author.name` vs `Book.name`), as doing `qb.select(['a.*', 'b.*'])` will result in query `select a.*, b.* ...` and the duplicate columns would not be correctly mapped.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/query-builder/#mapping-raw-results-to-entities

About the `autoLoadEntities` thing, never heard of that, will take a look how it works, but in general, the nestjs adapter is not developed by me, so if its something only nest related, it would be better to ask on their GH repo.

Or you could use folder based discovery (`entitiesDirs`).

**here is the new example with 3 entities:**

```js
return this.authorRepository.findOne({ 
  key,
  books: { bookMetadata: localeKey } },
}, ['books.bookMetadata']);
```

This will produce 3 queries, one for each db table, but the first one will auto-join books and bookMetadata to be able to filter by them. The condition will be propagated down in the second and third query.

If you omit the populate parameter (`['books.bookMetadata']`), then only the first query will be fired and you will end up with books not being populated (but the Author will be queried with the joined condition).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Great, I've subscribed to this thread on Github, and I'm looking forward for the v4! In the meantime I'll take a closer look to your suggestions. I used the `createQueryBuilder` because then I wanted to add `where` conditions on the joined table.

Comment: Which is also possible with the EM api, thanks to auto-joining: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/#searching-by-referenced-entity-fields

Comment: You can also use `em.populate()` to populate the results from the QB: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/nested-populate/#populating-already-loaded-entities

Comment: Thank you! I tried with the `em.findOne` API and I'm able to create a working query using `where` conditions. However I'm still not able to populate correctly the returned object with any of the joined columns. Let's say I have a 3rd BookMetadata entity, where `BookEntity` can have many `BookMetadataEntity`. I would like to get 1 Author (where author.key = 'foo'), and populate the returned object with all its `Book`s and `BookMetadata`s (where bookMetadata.localeKey = 'fr'). Actually I'm still not able to get it work. I've completed the entities in my main post above if it's not very clear.

Comment: You still have there `.select(['a.*', 'b.*', 'c.*'])`, as I said, you can't select multiple entities, you need to select just the root one. If you want to go the manual mapping way, you need to make sure to manually alias all fields that could collide (so at leasts the PKs, as they are all `id`). Its much better to use EM api for this as then it will automatically propagate the conditions to the populate queries. Check the updated example at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Sorry, I've updated the entities in my main post above, but not the query. With the `this.authorRepository.findOne` method the query is working well, but even with the populate parameter, joined tables are not populated. I checked the SQL queries and they are working well too, corresponding data are well retrieved. When debugging the returned object, instead of the populated tables, I see a Collection object with among others `{_populated: true, items: []}`....

Comment: ... I also made a test with the same DB and another ORM (from another branch) and everything are retrieved correctly. I think I'm still missing something, I might try again tomorrow or next week on a second look when I would be better rested. If I'm still stuck, I'll try to do a repro project on GitHub.